# Generating Silverlight service reference - how to tell what is causing proxy classes to be generated

Tags: silverlight, wcf, svcutil.exe, service-reference

I have a large object structure that I'm wanting to share between a .Net4 backend and a Silverlight 5 front end. I've created two class library projects of the appropriate type, and have my object structure implemented in the .Net library, and linked into the SL library. On the Silverlight client side I am referencing the Silverlight class library. When I generate the service reference I have checked the option to "Reuse types in referenced assemblies". However when I generate the service reference I am finding that types that are in referenced assemblies are still being generated. It is only certain types, and appears to be largely collection types (attributed with `<CollectionDataContract>`).

I have a main object that has many properties which are generally either `List<MyTypeA>` or in some cases they are `MyListTypeB`, where `MyListTypeB` inherits from `List<MyTypeB>`. It seems to be the classes similar to `MyListTypeB` that are causing the proxies to be generated. These are all attributed with `<CollectionDataContract>` and have a default constructor.

I also find that even though the project where I am adding the service reference to has a reference to the other SL *project* containing the entities, when I update the service a new reference directly to the dll is also being added to the project. I'm not sure why this is happening, or if it is causing confusion in the service proxy generation

Is there any way to tell what classes/properties are causing the service generation to generate proxy classes? Or is it a case of trial and error having to comment out attributes until they aren't generated and hone in on the problem class?

Comment: Hmmm. Ok, I found that The classes that were being generated in the proxy were really just the:

System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<MyTypeB>

type classes, and that by generating the proxy using SLSvcUtil with the /ct parameter prevents this from being generated. However working in a reasonably large team, I don't want devs to have to run slsvcutil. Is it possible to achieve this functionality through the Add Service Reference dialog?

Answer (score 0):

I have now found out about the use of the svcmap file, and updating the CollecitonMappings elements to include my collection types, described here:

http://mostlydevelopers.com/blog/post/2009/12/14/Configure-WCF-Service-ndash3b-Reuse-Collection-Types-Issue.aspx

It seems a little unusual that the svcmap functionality is so undocumented.

I was able to add an entry int he svcmap file similar to the following:

```
 <CollectionMappings>
  <CollectionMapping TypeName="MyNamespace.MyType" Category="List" />
 </CollectionMappings>
```

And then when I updated the service reference the proxy collections are not generated.